# Specifying active and failover jms connection through axis2 xml

Tags: java, web-services, jms, apache-axis, ems

I have a jms based webservice implemented in axis2 framework. It uses Tibco EMS for JMS queue and connection factory.
Currently I have defined the active EMS server connection in axis2.xml and works fine. However, if this server goes down for some reason, I need to update the ais2.xml manually to point to failover EMS server and then bounce my webservice.

How can I define both active and failover connection such that it switches automatically when active one goes down

Regards,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

In TIBCO EMS you can define an FT URL using the following syntax :
tcp://server:port,tcp://server:port

For example :
tcp://server1:7222,tcp://server2:7222

I think you should be able to use such connection URL in your framework.

Comment: Thanks. From TIBCO EMS perspective  that's fine. The question is how to specify these multiple server connections in axis2.xml

Comment: My typical axis2.xml containing the receiver details is as follows
<transportReceiver name="jms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener">
<parameter name="default">
<parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://myserverurl:7222</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">MyQueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>

Comment: <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.ConcurrentConsumers">6</parameter>         
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.MaxConcurrentConsumers">6</parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.UserName">myusername</parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.Password">mypassword</parameter>
<parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">connection</parameter>
</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

Comment: If you are using JNDI I would do that :
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tibjmsnaming:/server1:7222,tibjmsnaming://server2:7222,</parameter>

And then I would configure the factories with the following :

[TopicConnectionFactory]
  type                  = topic
  url                   = tcp://server1:7222,tcp://server2:7222

[QueueConnectionFactory]
  type                  = queue
  url                   = tcp://server1:7222,tcp://server2:7222